# Meta image for homepage and meta image for facebook share

Tags: html, image, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I need to put meta og:image for homepage, and meta og:image for facebook share to get featured image from posts. Now when im sharing posts, facebook let me choose from these 2 images, i like by default only featured image to be shown on share.

Homepage image is not working, on Sharing Debugger i get Provided og:image URL, was not a valid URL. Image on blog posts working

```
    <?php if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ): ?>

  <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/aktivirajse.png ?>">

  <?php else: ?>

<meta property="og:image" content="<?php $post_thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID),'large'); echo $post_thumbnail[0]; ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: And …? What is the actual image URL your system outputs?

Comment: <meta property="og:image" content=""> Its empty, and when i share it on fb, get random image from homepage

Comment: Which of the two cases are you talking about now, sharing the home page, or a specific post?

Comment: sharing the homepage

Comment: Looks like you are outputting an extra `?>` _inside_ the `content` attribute value.